# Joining on the same key on the next row

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose we have a table which contains `customer_id`, `order_date`, and `ship_date`. A reorder of the product occurs when the *same* customer's next `order_date` is within `30` days of the last `ship_date`.

```
select * from mytable

customer_id       order_date      ship_date
   1              2017-08-04      2017-08-09
   1              2017-09-01      2017-09-05
   2              2017-02-02      2017-03-01
   2              2017-04-05      2017-04-09
   2              2017-04-15      2017-04-19       
   3              2018-02-02      2018-03-01
```

Requested: Reorders

```
customer_id       order_date      ship_date
   1              2017-09-01      2017-09-05
   2              2017-04-15      2017-04-19
```

How can I retrieve only the records for the *same* customers who had reorders, next `order_date` within **30**
days of the last `ship_date`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use exists as follows:

```
Select * from your_table t
Where exists (select 1 from your_table tt
Where tt.customer_id = t.customer_id
  And t.ship_date > tt.ship_date
  and t.ship_date <= dateadd(day, 30, tt.ship_date))
```

Comment: had to tweak the query little bit but this work impeccably, thanks Popeye!

Answer (score 1):

One method is `lead()`:

```
select t.customer_id, t.order_date, t.next_ship_date
from (select t.*,
             lead(order_date) over (partition by customer_id order by order_date) as next_order_date
             lead(ship_date) over (partition by customer_id order by order_date) as next_ship_date
     from t
    ) t
where next_order_date < dateadd(day, 30, ship_date);
```

EDIT:

If you want the "reorder" row, just use `lag()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(ship_date) over (partition by customer_id order by order_date) as prev_ship_date
     from t
    ) t
where prev_ship_date > dateadd(day, 30, order_date);
```

Comment: Thanks, this query returns the `first` and the `fourth` rows from the table while my request is to retrieve the `second` and the `fifth` rows. Any ideas?